# python add elements in a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

i have done the following code in order to fill a tuple with user input and then add the elements of the tuple.For example giving as input 1,2 and 3,4 i have the tuple :
((1,2),(3,4)).Then i want to add 1+2  and 3+4.

This is the first part which works ok:

```
data=[]
mytuple=()

while True:
    myinput=raw_input("Enter two integers: ")
    if not myinput:
        print("Finished")
        break
    else: 
        myinput.split(",")
        data.append(myinput)
        mytuple=tuple(data)
print(data)
print(mytuple)
```

Then , try sth like:

```
for adding in mytuple:
    print("{0:4d} {1:4d}".format(adding)) # i am not adding here,i just print
```

I have two problems:
1) I don't know how to add the elements.
2) When i add the second part of the code(the adding) ,when i press enter instead of causing the break of the program it continues to ask me "Enter two integers"

Thank you!

Comment: you want to add the numbers.. but what do you want to do with the results?

Comment: I want to print the results with the format function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
myinput = myinput.split(",")
```

and

```
data.append( (int(myinput[0]), int(myinput[1])) )
```

and

```
for adding in mytuple:
    print("{0:4d}".format(adding[0] + adding[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the built-in [map function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map):

```
data=[]
mytuple=()

while True:
    myinput=raw_input("Enter two integers: ")
    if not myinput:
        print("Finished")
        break
    else: 
        myinput=map(int,myinput.split(","))                  # (1)
        data.append(myinput)
        mytuple=tuple(data)

print(data)
# [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print(mytuple)
# ([1, 2], [3, 4])
print(' '.join('{0:4d}'.format(sum(t)) for t in mytuple))    # (2)
#    3    7
```

1. Use `map(int,...)` to convert the strings to integers. Also note there is an error here in the orginal code. `myinput.split(",")` is an expression, not an assignment. To change the value of `myinput` you'd have to say `myinput = myinput.split(...)`.
2. Use `map(sum,...)` to apply sum to each tuple in `mytuple`.

Comment: :Thanks a lot for the answer but i don't know yet the map function.Is there another way?Also, i want to use the "format" function.

Comment: @George: You could also use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions): `[sum(t) for t in mytuple]`

Comment: your printing assumes that there were two entries (pairs).

Comment: I want to input pairs.Not only 2 entries,but in order to understand how it works iuse 2.Also,i don't know yet list comprehension:)

Comment: @George: see my answer for beginner-level solution but both list comprehensions and `map` + `filter` are great tools and can create a lot more terse code. learn them ;)

Comment: @unutbu:Thank you a lot,I don't know yet these tools but thanks for the knowledge.